# Kawamata-Viehweg Vanishing Theorem for Excellent Surfaces 

Tags: birational-geometry, positive-characteristic, ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there any version of Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing theorem that holds for excellent surfaces? I will be very glad if there is one such, but if not then is it at least true for a surface over a non algebraically closed field of char $p>0$?

More particularly I have the following situation:

$X$ is a variety of dimension $n$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$. Let $x$ be a codimension $2$ point of $X$ and $S=\text{Spec }\mathcal{O}_{X,\ x}$. Then $S$ is a surface over the residue field $k(x)$ ( which is not algebraically closed ). I need to use Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing theorem ( at least some relative version of it ) on this $S$. I know that one version of this vanishing theorem holds for surfaces over an algebraically closed field of char $p>0$ by Hiromu Tanaka ( The $X$-methods for klt surfaces in positive characteristic ).

Comment: Doesn't Kodaira vanishing fail for surfaces in positive characteristic? Raynaud gave counterexamples.

Comment: Yes Angelo you are right, Kadaira vanishing does fail in char positive even on a surface, but some version of Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing theorem which is sufficient to the run the Minimal Model Program  continues to hold even in positive characteristic for surfaces. You can look for a reference in the paper I mentioned above or in a preprint by Kollar and Kovacs, "Birational Geometry of Log Surfaces"

Comment: Presumably for surfaces non-algebraically closed fields, depending on exactly what you want, perhaps things are ok by some base change (perhaps as long as your exceptional set is geometrically *whatever*)?

If you are looking for references, I know that some Grauert-Riemenschneider-type statements are even true for excellent two dimensional rings (see for example the work of Lipman on resolution of 2 dimensional singularities and also his work on rational singularities in any characteristic).  

Can you be more precise in terms of what exactly you need?

Comment: Since the usual version of the Kawamata-Viehweg vanishing theorem generalized Kodaira's, you'd better write down the exact statement that you need.

Comment: I don't understand "over $k(x)$". Clearly $S$ is a two-dimensional local scheme with closed point $\mathrm{Spec}\,k(x)$, but in general it is not a $k(x)$-scheme in any natural way.

Comment: Hi Karl and Angelo, thanks for taking time to read my problem. Here is exactly what I have and what I need. 
Let $X$ be a normal variety over an algebraically closed filed $k$ of char $p>0$. Let $x$ be codim $2$ point of $X$. Assume $S=\text{Spec }\mathcal{O}_{X,\ x}$. Then $S$ is a surface over the field $k(x)$. 
Now by Lipman, $S$ has a resolution of singularities, call $f:Y\to S$. Let $B$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier $\mathbb{Q}$ divisor such that $B$ is $f$-nef and $f$-big and the fractional part of $B$ has SNC support. Then $R^if_*\mathcal{O}_X(K_Y+\lceil B\rceil)=0$ for all $i>0$.

Comment: Hi Laurent, You are right, $S$ does bot have any ''natural'' $k(x)$-scheme structure but there is a obvious  ''non natural'' $k(x)$-scheme structure, since I started with a Variety $X$, so $k(x)\hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,\ x}$ and the only reason for doing this is to get a finite type morphism so that I can say $S$ is a variety. Now that you asked about it, I am little worried, is $\mathcal{O}_{X,\ x}$ a finitely generated $k(x)$ algebra ? I always thought it is, but now I am not so sure!

Comment: No, a localization is practically never finitely generated. The local rings that are of finite type over a field are artinian.

Comment: Thanks Angelo, could you please give a proof of this fact or probably suggest a reference?

Comment: It follows easily from the fact that a finitely dimensional algebra is Jacobson; in particular, the closed points are dense. So, if there is only one closed point, the spectrum consists of that point, so the algebra is 0-dimensional, hence artinian.

Comment: @Omprokash Das: it is not true in general that you can embed $k(x)$ into $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ or even into the function field of $X$. Example: assume $k$ is not algebraically closed, take $X=\mathbb{P}^n_k$ and take for $x$ a closed point with residue field $\neq k$. Variant: same $X$ ($n\geq2$,  $k$ arbitrary), $x$= generic point of a non-unirational subvariety, e.g. a curve of positive genus.